# Show popover on Submit button when inputs are empty

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, popover

I have a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cwalC89dm9OFp111W1In?p=preview

As per this, user should enter input numbers for student id and marks. if you noticed, it will result in a popover on input messages if number is not between 0 and 10. this works fine.

I have a submit button. I want the popover to show at the submit button if the user has not entered any values in the above fields. how can i achieve this ? 
can someone please shed some light here ?

Here is the code for it...

HTML Code-

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<br>
<form name="myForm" class="myForm" novalidate>
  Student Id: <input popover="Should be between 1 and 10" name="myInput" ng-model="test" 
        popover-toggle="myForm.myInput.$error.max" max="10" type="number" ng-maxlength="2" required
        popover-placement="top" />

  Marks: <input popover="Should be between 1 and 10" name="myInput1" ng-model="test1"
        popover-toggle="myForm.myInput1.$error.max" max="10" type="number" required
        popover-placement="top" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/BS2Z5k0XJ6hFsYrUPyVR?p=preview) the correct behavior? That is and will be my best try as the code is hardly understandable.

Comment: Ayesha I'm not expert in angular so can't help properly but its always good to display errors at relevant input fields rather than form submitting buttons. Please refer to angular docs for forms/error handling which may help you a lot: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: @Lucio- i get wat you are tring to do. this is exactly what i am looking for. however it doesnt fulfil properly...